# HTTP Post. Content body from pipe/file handle in Perl

Tags: perl, stream, http-post, pipe

I have a tool, that generates some data and prints it to stdout.
In my perl script i need to launch this tool and send the produced data to a http server using Post request. The tool generates a lot of data and it might be very time consuming to save it on the disk and only than send it. So i really want to send it on the fly, let's say redirect the stdout to http post request.
Content-Length should not be a big deal, because i know the data size.

I already tried to use callbacks:

```
  my @chunk = qw( foo bar baz );
  my $req = HTTP::Request::StreamingUpload->new(
      PUT      => 'http://example.com/foo.cgi',
      callback => sub { shift @chunk },
      headers => HTTP::Headers->new(
          'Content-Type'   => 'text/plain',#and multipart/form-data
          'Content-Length' => 9,
      ),
  );
  my $res = LWP::UserAgent->new->request($req);
```

and reading from a fh:

```
 open my $fh, '<', '/your/upload/requestbody' or die $!;
  my $req = HTTP::Request::StreamingUpload->new(
      PUT     => 'http://example.com/foo.cgi',
      fh      => $fh,
      headers => HTTP::Headers->new(
          'Content-Length' => 9,
      ),
  );
  my $res = LWP::UserAgent->new->request($req);
```

But for some reason it doesn't work for me and i receive error 500.
Also i know for sure that the server supports multipart/form-data

Is there any example? Is there any other way to redirect stdout to my http post request?

Comment: error 500 means the URL you're posting to didn't work - what errors are in the webserver logs?

Comment: I don't have the server logs.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone, i decided to create a socket and write the data manually. Works fine.